# Show license agreement before download

Tags: typo3, eula

I have to solve the following task for our university homepage:

- Whenever a pdf is requested the user has to accept a license, which pops up.
- On Agree the download starts. If not, no download is possible.

I searched through the extensions but did not find any extension doing the job. Maybe you know one...

So I tried to implement my own extension. Taking the strengths of **securelinks** (*Allows access control to files from a configurable directory ... presents a license acceptation prior to download*) and **naw_securedl** (*"Secure Download": Apply TYPO3 access rights to ALL file assets (PDFs, TGZs or JPGs etc. - configurable) - protect them from direct access.*) I wanted to combine both extensions to have one that:

1. whenever a pdf file is requested (naw_securedl)
2. a license is shown and in case of ACCEPT a redirect to the file happens (securelinks).

This task sounds very easy, since I only have to combine both tasks. Anyway, I failed.

How do you solve this problem?
Do you know some extension doing the job?
Is anyone interested in a cooperation in which we try to create an extension thats doing the job?

Thanks for your help in advance!

Comment: BTW: This might not be the right place to ask for cooperation. People are focussed on answering programming-related questions at SO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that all donwloads are stored in one folder, I'd recommend writing your own little extension that replaces every link with a link to an intermediate site, like this:
`www.mydomain.com/acceptlicense.html?downloadfile=myhighqualitycontent.pdf`.

On the *accept license page*, users need to check the accept license checkbox, then click a submit button, which leads them to the *download page*, still carrying the GET parameter:
`www.mydomain.com/download.html?downloadfile=myhighqualitycontent.pdf`.

If not all files are in the same folder, you can replace slashes in the file path with other characters (they need to work in the URL). Or you might need a database table that indexes the files, so you can use IDs for the download files:
`www.mydomain.com/acceptlicense.html?downloadfileID=99`

If you don't know at all how to write TYPO3 extensions, consider using individual php/html files out of the TYPO3 context.

Comment: Thank you for this answear. But as you were assuming I do not now how to write TYPO3 extensions. Neither I knew how to use individual php/html files out of the TYPO3 context. 

The problem has been solved by switching the Core. We're running django now.